# How to test if a method is called using pytest

Tags: python, django, mocking, pytest, pytest-django

I want to write a unit test to check if a method is being called. Is there any way to do it. Or i am misunderstanding the way mock can be used here? As this way mocked_method is always called but without any args.

```
@(pytest.parameterize)
def test(jsonrpc_proxy):
    jsonrpc_proxy.method1_call()
    # Method 1 should not call method 2
    with mock.patch('method2') as mocked_method:
        assert ((args),) not in mocked_track.call_args_list

    # do something 
    jsonrpc_proxy.method1_call()
    # Method 1 should call method 2
    with mock.patch('method2') as mocked_method:
        assert ((args),) in mocked_track.call_args_list
```

PS: I have checked other questions related to it before posting, but i think i am misunderstanding the whole concept about how we use mock in such scenarios. Please enlighten me as i am new to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to call `method1` when `method2` is patched, not before that.
try moving the call inside the with statement:

```
with mock.patch('method2') as mocked_method:
    jsonrpc_proxy.method1_call()
    assert ((args),) not in mocked_track.call_args_list
```

Comment: Usually it's a good idea to assert for a defined call with `mocked_method.assert_called_with(arguments...)`.